# Save the output from a Powershell command to a variable

Tags: powershell

im trying to save the output from a command to a variable,
but i just cant get it to work.
It should look something like this :

`$test = (Get-SmbShare | Select Name,CurrentUsers,CurrentUserLimit | fl)`

`Write-Host $test`

Output: The Output of Get-SmbShare

Comment: @Cid the variable is empty , it shows nothing with `Write-Host $test`

Comment: [1] DO NOT use the `Format-*` commands unless you are sending the output to a plain text file OR to the screen. those cmdlets destroy your objects and give you formatting code wrapped around the butchered bits of your objects. ///// [2] at what point in your pipeline do you NOT get any output?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thats what i want to do, the output is gonna go into a text file.

Comment: ok. [*grin*] **_PLEASE, answer the #2 question._**

Comment: @Lee_Dailey im really new to Powershell sorry, the command `Get-SmbShare | Select Name,CurrentUsers,CurrentUserLimit | fl` works fine, its just that the result from it does not get saved into the variable

Comment: If that textual (formatted for **display only**) output is what you really want to store in the `$test` variable, then add `| Out-String` to the line. (you can also remove the brackets around it as in this case they don't do anything useful)

Comment: @Jan - your code works for me. the `$Test` variable contains the text that the `fl` call sends out. you may want to test the line of code in another session ... perhaps a new `powershell.exe` console.

Comment: @Theo that does not work for me sadly

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i tried and it did not work, it only prints `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData` and more stuff like that

Comment: that is what you get from the `Format-*` cmdlets. REMOVE IT from your pipeline.

Comment: Appending another pipe to `Out-String` really does work. Edit your question and show us what you have yried there. BTW. I strongly agree with @Lee_Dailey that you should only use `Format-*` cmdlets to output to the display, nothing else.

Comment: @Jan - you are quite welcome! glad to have helped a little bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking through the comments and I saw you said that you want to store it in a text file.

> @Lee_Dailey Thats what i want to do, the output is gonna go into a text file. – Jan

So if you want to skip the variable part and just send it straight to a text file, you could use:

```
Get-SmbShare | Select Name, CurrentUsers, CurrentUserLimit | fl | Out-File -filepath "C:\Temp\file.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , sadly it isnt that simple for me. the SmbFiles are on a server, i connect to it via `Invoke-command`, then read the infos from the server. The text file however is on my User so i cant directly save them, thats why i tried saving them into an variable so i can disconnect from the server and then save it into my file, but that does also not work sadly